# AngularJS: $q.race() in old angular versions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Angular 1.5.8 implements a `$q.race()` method which takes an array of promises and returns a promise which is resolves with the value of the first resolved promise.

However i am stuck with angular 1.4 for now and need some kind of functionality like a `$q.any` or `$q.race` method.

Currently I use flags inside `.then()` to "remember" the state of promises which obviously is not ideal.

```
var resolvedPromise = null;

promise1.then(function(data){
  if(!resolvedPromise === 'promise2'){
    resolvedPromise = 'promise1';
    successcallback(data)
  }
})

promise2.then(function(data){
  if(!resolvedPromise === 'promise1'){
    resolvedPromise = 'promise2';
    successcallback(data)
  }
})
```

**Question**

I only need this to work for two promises at a time:

```
myRaceFkt(p1,p2)
  .then(successcallback)
```

Is there a more elegant solution without having access to the improved `$q`-api of 1.5.8?

Comment: what exactly are you wanting to do?

Comment: One of the benefits of open source - you can look at their implementation yourself: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L635

Comment: given two promises `q1` and `q2`, i want to call a function immediately when one of the promises resolves. The parameter for the functioncall needs to be the data with which the promise was resolved.

Comment: @JoeClay thanks! I tried to add this to my `$q`-Service by using `$provide.decorator('$q', function($delegate){ $delegate.race = ...}`, but got stuck because the $delegate does not seem to be an object which i can extend. Can anyone give me a hint on the syntax here?

Answer (score 1):

```
function myRaceFn(promises){
   return $q(function(resolve, reject) { 
     promises.forEach(function(promise) {
       promise.then(resolve, reject);
     });
   });
}
myRaceFn([promise1, promise2]).then(....
```

Comment: why do you use `.bind(defer)`? I tried this without calling bind and it seems to work as intended

Comment: When you use object method, you never know, has it this reference or not. So it safe to use bind and unsafe without reading source code