# Using $q.race to add a timeout to a $q promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have a function that returned `$q.defer().promise`.
In other function I call this function and do `then` on this promise.

I tried to find out how I can do timeout on this promise in order to reject him but the only thing that I found is how to do timeout on `$http` function.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my engish.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some codes

Comment: hint: `Promise.race`

Comment: https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisetimeoutms-message if you have a Q promise, there's a `timeout` method

Comment: Works with `$q` promise? @JaromandaX

Comment: I don't use this Q promise @Sheng

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994871/setting-a-timeout-handler-on-a-promise-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a promise that can timeout from another promise, use [$q.race](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#race)

```
var dataPromise = service.getData();

var timeoutPromise = $timeout(function(){}, 2000);

timeoutPromise = timeoutPromise
  .then(function() {
    return $q.reject("Timeout");
});

var dataOrTimeoutPromise = $q.race([dataPromise, timeoutPromise]);
```

The above example creates a promise that will resolve with data or reject with the reason "Timeout" after 2000 milliseconds whichever comes first.

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference ($q.race)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#race)

---

> This is looks good but I use angular 1.5.7 and this function added in angular 1.5.8. `Promise.race` will do the same or should I implement this method like here [`$q.race()` in old angular versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489360/angularjs-q-race-in-old-angular-versions).

If you use `Promise.race`, it is important to convert it to a $q promise with [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when):

```
var dataOrTimeoutPromise = $q.race([dataPromise, timeoutPromise]);

//OR

var dataOrTimeoutPromise = $q.when(Promise.race([dataPromise, timeoutPromise]));
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. Use `$q.when` to bring the ES6 promise into the AngularJS execution context.

From the Docs:

> ### $q.when
>
> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.
>
> [— AngularJS $q Service API Reference (q.when)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when)

Comment: This is looks good but I use angular 1.5.7 and this function added in angular 1.5.8. `Promise.race` will do the same or should I implement this method like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489360/angularjs-q-race-in-old-angular-versions