# What is the difference between $q.race to Promise.race?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, es6-promise

I am using Angularjs version 1.5.7 and `$q.race` function added in version 1.5.8.

I saw that there is function `Promise.race` and my question if there is any difference between those functions.

If there is difference should I copy the function from here: [AngularJS: $q.race() in old angular versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489360/angularjs-q-race-in-old-angular-versions)
and it will works the same like `$q.race`?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english!

Comment: The obvious difference would be that one returns an angular promise while the other returns an ES6 promise :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript ES6 specifications introduced the method you described above, like `Promise.race`, `Promise.all` etc..
The difference is basically that angular has a built-in `$q` service in order to manage with promises. 
This will trigger automatically the digest cycle in order to change everything that could be related to the data returned by the promises or all the involved operations. 
If you are allowed to use ES6 specification, you can use directly all the built-in Promises of JavaScript, but then you have to manually trigger the $digest in order to make all the changes happen. 
This is one of the main differences between the usage of $q or standard Promises in angularjs. 
Moreover, there are a lot of related methods in angular which integrates with $q, like $http for example, and for your tests, you will have your life easier treating directly with $q. 
So my suggestion is to use $q if possible.

Comment: If I use `Promise.race` then I should trigger `$digest` in the `then` function of the promise that returns from the race?

Comment: yes and be sure to trigger the $digest relative to the scope which contains the involved changes.

Answer (score 0):

The core difference is that $q.race will call $rootScope.$apply() under the hood to digest any changes that may occurred after executing your promise callback.
Promise A+ spec has noting to do with that since Promise.all, Promise.race are defined in ES6/ES2015 spec not in Promise A+ spec

Comment: where did you read that $q.race triggers all the $rootScope $apply method? Are you sure that this is not related in general with $q and this has nothing to do with the specific `.race` method?